# Loading different views depending on the android versions

Tags: android

Well, I was wondering whether I could load different views from same application for different android versions. I thought that I could create an activity that can call one of the two separate activities defined for different versions of android via intent. I mean suppose that in one activity I have used action bar which is available from ice cream sandwich only, and other could possibly to use views in earlier android releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For layout that support multiple screens you can refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

2) If you want to load different layout depending on different android version then you can create different layout xml files and then in the activity, for example below code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
     // only for android older than gingerbread
     //call setContentView with your layout
}
```

3) You can have layout in  layout-v(version-number) folder inside your res folder. Where for example for SDK 11 the folder name will be layout-v11

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Create a layout-vX folder in your res, where X is the version number (11 for Honeycomb, for example).  Any file in there will override the version of the file in the layout directory if using version X or higher.

Answer (score 0):

if all you need this is for the action bar , i highly recommend using [actionbarsherlock library](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) .

you can also do the checking of the version using code (read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)) :

```
 if(VERSION.SDK_... <VERSION_CODES.... )
```

and by setting the qualifier of the version , as written [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) , so for example, for resources that need to be used on API 11 and higher , put the qualifier v11 .

Comment: Here is the prob, if i set the min sdk to ginger_bread, would actionbar library be still available to me ?

Comment: Sure . However  ,you should use the one of the library and not of android . In fact , the minSdk can be set to much lower than GB . Most of the functions,methods , classes and resources related to this library start with Sherlock ("abs" for the resources) or have the word "sherlock" in some way or another .

Comment: So, i think you are asking to grab the library for action bar and attach it to project.

I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Gaurav, actionbarsherlock is not the android library but very famous library to support actionbar in the versions of android which does not support action bar. It is easy to use, and there are examples available on their site.  Just google search actiobarsherlock.

Comment: He can use the same link i've given. The library is very good and google has recommended using it in one of its lectures. Don't forget to test it on devices with old versions , just in case you haven't used it well (it's easy to confuse ) .

Comment: I just noticed that you updated the answer with link. I think anyway, we both want him to go to right place.

Comment: yes sorry about this. sometimes, i edit my answers a lot (thinking : oh i forgot to put this , oh he might want to read this,... ) .